# Can not launch Google authenticator app by deeplink on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

On iOS 14 or lower, I'm able to launch Google Authenticator app by deep link as the code below:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "otpauth://")!)`

However, it does not work on iOS 15 anymore. It seems iOS 15 does not allow to trigger Google Authenticator app by deep link. I also tried on my phone browser with "otpauth://". It's only able to open the app with iOS 14. Can anyone help me about this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure, does your app declares `otpauth` in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

Comment: yes. I already.

Comment: @CongPhu, Did you find the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this schema : `googleauthenticator://`

Comment: Not working for me. Is this working for you?

Comment: Hi, do you have any more details on the url scheme?