# Opening google authenticator with googleauthenticator:// scheme with new account prefilled on ios 15

Tags: ios, authentication, deep-linking, ios15, google-authenticator

In my app I've been using otpauth:// deep link schema to open the 2fa authentication details on google authenticator. Users then had to only confirm saving the 2fa secret. iOS 15 broke this on google authenticator and opens the link in apples password manager. I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016987/19305553) to use googleauthenticator:// scheme instead, and that works in opening up the google authenticator. However, the parameters / path of the scheme is no longer working as it used to be, and I couldn't find the documentation of googleauthenticator:// scheme anywhere.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, couldn't find a solution and opted out of deeplinking to google authenticator on ios.